# A sign in C++ I've never seen before: |=

Tags: c++

I have some code here:

```
case MONITORTYPE_WUXGA_SXGA_WXGA:
    bResult |= (var == enum1);
    bResult |= (var == enum2);
```

Now i know what its doing but I don't know what the |= is. Can anyone tell me there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
a |= b
```

is the same as

```
a = a | b
```

which is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operation.

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to:

```
bResult = bResult | (var == enum1);
```

Just like `a += b` means `a = a + b`, `a |= b` means `a = a | b`.

Answer (score 3):

For most binary operators `♢` in C++ (except comparison operators, relational operators and boolean operators), there exists a corresponding compound assignment operator, `♢=`.

That is, `|=` is simply the compound assignment operator for `|` which is bitwise or. Its use is completely equivalent to `+=`, `*=` etc. So

```
a |= b;
// is equivalent to
a = a | b;
```

Comment: There are also binary operators that don't have a corresponding assignment, like for example `&&` and `>`

Comment: @sth Damn. I’ll fix my answer then.

Comment: I think the proper terminology is not assignment operator but [compound assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise OR.  It means the same as `bResult = bResult | (value)`.  In this case, it is setting bResult to true if var is either enum1 or enum2.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the *bitwise or* Operator. `a |= b` is equal to `a = a | b`.

More on bitwise operations: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation